# Python: does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I have two date time dataframes which looks like:
df1:

```
0   2020-03-16 14:00:00
1   2020-03-16 17:00:00
2   2020-03-16 20:00:00
3   2020-03-16 20:00:00
4   2020-03-16 19:00:00
5   2020-03-16 12:00:00
6   2020-03-16 18:00:00
```

df2:

```
0   2020-03-16 09:00:00
1   2020-03-16 09:00:00
2   2020-03-16 09:00:00
3   2020-03-16 08:30:00
4   2020-03-16 08:30:00
5   2020-03-16 08:30:00
6   2020-03-16 09:00:00
```

I wanted to delete df2 from df1 and convert the result into minutes. For that purpose I am converting each dataframe into datetime.strptime by using following code:

```
datetime.strptime(df1.to_string(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However, when I run above code, it throws an error message of Value error and it says that value does not match format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. Could anyone point out where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Parentheses are correct now.

Comment: Those dates are not valid. For some reason they start with a single digit number before the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
pd.to_datetime(df1.date, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # I named my column 'date'
```

The reason it's not working is that when you use `to_string()` it gives something like this:

```
Out[78]: '0   2020-03-15 09:00:00\n1   2020-03-15 09:00:00\n2   2020-03-15 08:30:00\n3
```

Here's my full code after copying your example `dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=0, header=None)
df1['date'] = df1.iloc[:, 0] + ' ' + df1.iloc[:, 1]
pd.to_datetime(df1.date, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```